# Can't Integrate youtube to fragment

Tags: java, android

```
youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
```

Unreachable statement:

```
public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment {
private FragmentActivity myContext;
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment;
private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
private static final String YoutubeDeveloperKey = "xyz";
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
        myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
    }

    super.onAttach(activity);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_fragment2, container, false);


    youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("AIzaS", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                YPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
                YPlayer.loadVideo("2zNSgSzhBfM");
                YPlayer.play();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Hi sanchit. You won't ever get to the mentioned line of your `onCreateView` function because you are returning `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_fragment2, container, false);` right at the beginning. When you return something from a function, it exits the function.

Answer (score 1):

change your code like below. You have return statement before everything, so it is saying unreachable code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_fragment2, container, false);


    youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("AIzaS", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                YPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
                YPlayer.loadVideo("2zNSgSzhBfM");
                YPlayer.play();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

return view;
    }
```

Hope it helps!!! Just check these things while you code else these silly mistakes will take your valuable time ;)